# Sikuli IDE syntax test report error

Tags: automated-testing, test-report, sikuli

I just have a head start on Sikuli. I am not sure why I am getting an error. There is a double-click mismatch error.

This is my sample code

```
    from sikuli import *
    import unittest
    import HTMLTestRunner

    class mytest (unittest.TestCase):

    doubleClick("1.png");
    type("demo")
    doubleClick("2.png");

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(sikuil)
    outfile = open("C:\\Sikuli\\Reports\\report.html", "w") # path to report folder
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile, title=' Report Title', description='desc..' )
    runner.run(suite)
```

Error message

```
[error] script [ sikuil ] stopped with error in line 7 at column 0
[error] SyntaxError ( "mismatched input '' expecting INDENT", )
```

Comment: You have a class definition without a body...

Answer (score 1):

Your code example misses [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) after the class line.

I think Sikuli uses Jython, which must use spaces:

> 4 spaces for indentation, no tabs.
>
> https://wiki.python.org/jython/CodingStandards

So your error is probably caused by the lack of indentation, or mixing tabs and spaces.

Your code should look like this in the IDE, but **the empty line also needs spaces as indentation**.

```
class mytest (unittest.TestCase):

    doubleClick("1.png");
```

Maybe just remove the empty lines.